# Android connected via USB gives inconsistent ID

Tags: usb, android

I have an LG Android phone.  When I connect it to my Kubuntu box with a USB cable, it shows up, as it should, with lsusb.  But the ID code is inconsistent: if I shut the Android off and restart it, the ID changes:

Bus 003 Device 029: ID 1004:61f9 LG Electronics, Inc.

and later

Bus 003 Device 031: ID 1004:61a6 LG Electronics, Inc.

That makes it impossible to make a consistent entry in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Totally normal behaviour. You should be able to write

```
ATTRS{isProduct}="61f9|61a6"
```

or

```
ATTRS{idProduct}="61*"
```

Comment: The trouble is that I keep seeing IDs that I haven't seen before.

Comment: And the different IDs don't even have a common prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using ATTRS{isProduct}=="*" will work no matter what the product ID is.